# How to change home directory when running `yarn`?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I have a nodejs project and using `yarn` to build it. For some reasons, the user home directory is read-only. When I run `yarn install` in my project I get below error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/jenkins/.config'".
```

it seems that `yarn` is trying to access user home directory. How can I restrict `yarn` only use current application directory?

I know for `npm` I can use below environment varaible but I am not sure about how to do that in `yarn`.

```
export npm_config_cache=npm-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Yarn uses local packages cache, typically it's located in user's home directory.

To resolve your problem you could try do the following:

1. Change cache directory:
   `yarn install --cache-folder ./path_to_public_directory`
2. Or run yarn with sudo:
   `sudo yarn install`